# Pandas df converted to pyspark df throws type error for column with null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have this problem, I am loading data in xlsx file with a lot of columns from local directory and I need to convert it to pyspark dataframe. Unfortunately, one of the columns contains date values that can be null, which causes this exception:

```
Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.TimestampType'>
```

What Im doing is just reading file:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path_to_file, sheet_name='some_data')
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

I cannot read it with spark.read.format('com.crealytics.spark.excel'), because for some reason I am forbidden to install winutils.
I am aware that I shall either fill in nulls in pandas dataframe, cast it to string and once I get the pyspark df, then re-cast it to DateType() or pass the schema into the .schema() method, but the question I have is:

1. which of these would be "better"?
2. can I pass to the schema only type of the columns that can contain nulls? because the whole dataframe contains 100+ columns and I get this issue with only one of these columns.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you could provide minimal simulation data please, so we could regenerate the problem